# toggle-btn won't show up next to sidebar

Tags: html, css

First of all I'm using Django, and I've my CSS inside of my HTML file.

Here's what my situation looks like as of right now: I've finished setting a sidebar for the dashboard, aka the members area, and I want to offer users the option to show or hide the latter, just like most popular website nowadays do, including Youtube.

I've the following code in the body:

```
<div class="toggle-btn">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
```

And the following one in the head

```
 <style type="text/css">
      .toggle-btn {
          position:absolute;
          left:230px;
          top:20px;

      }

      .toggle-btn span {
          display:block;
          width:30px;
          height:5px;
          background:#151719;
          margin: 5px 0px;

      }

  </style>
```

It is indeed supposed to look just [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ABSj.png) , but nothing shows up next to the sidebar. If someone could point out what I might have done wrong, or missed doing, I would super appreciate it.

Comment: could you add some more HTML/CSS Code?
It could be a positioning problem, but it's hard to identify like this

Comment: Yes, it's indeed a position problem, I changed top:20px; to top:60px; and it suddenly worked :)

Comment: Well done. Finding the solution by yourself is always nice :)